# change (or set ) encoding web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a web service using JAX-WS API (a soap web service).

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class Accounts {
    public String getFullName(String userID){
        AccountManager GFN = new AccountManager();
        return GFN.getFullName(userID);
    }
```

what can I do to change it's encoding to "UTF-8" (for non-English character)?
I fount something like "@Produces("text/html; charset=UTF-8")" but it is for JAX-RS (restful web service)  i need something for JAX-WS. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To start, you need to get a hold of the SOAP message as early as possible. The best place to start is a [`javax.xml.ws.handler.LogicalHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/LogicalHandler.html) (as opposed to the more common type of handler, [`SOAPHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html)).

The `LogicalHandler`  intercepts the SOAP payload before the `SOAPHandler`, so it's the ideal place to do this

Within this handler, you have the liberty to whatever you want with the message, long before the encoding becomes a problem. Your code should look something like this

```
public class YourHandler implements LogicalHandler{

    public boolean handleMessage(LogicalMessageContext context) {
    boolean inboundProperty= (boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_INBOUND_PROPERTY);

         if (inboundProperty) {
              LogicalMessage lm = context.getMessage();
              Source payload = lm.getPayload();
              Source recodedPayload = modifyEncoding(payload); //This is where you change the encoding. We'll talk more about this
              lm.setPayload(recodedPayload) //remember to stuff the payload back in there, otherwise your change will not be registered
         } 

    return true;
    }   

}
```

So now you have the message. How to handle the change of encoding can be tricky, but it's completely up to you.

You have the option of setting the encoding on the entire message, or navigating (with [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)) to the field you're interested in and manipulating just that. Even for those two options, there are several ways of accomplishing both. I'm going to go the lazy route: set the encoding on the entire payload:

```
     private Source modifyEncoding(Source payload){
         StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
         StreamSource newSource = null;     
             try {
                  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); //this determines the outcome of the transformation
                  StreamResult output =  new StreamResult(sw);
                  transformer.transform(source, output);
                  StringReader sReader = new StringReader(sw.toString());
                  newSource = new StreamSource(sReader);//Stuff the re-encoded xml back in a Source
             } catch(Exception e){
               ex.printStackTrace();
             }
         return newSource;
     }
```

---

After the `LogicalHandler`, you now have the `SOAPHandler`. Here, setting the encoding is more straightforward, but its behaviour is implementation-dependent. Your `SOAPHandler` can look like this:

```
   public class YourSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler{

        public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext msgCtxt){
        boolean inbound = (boolean)msgCtxt.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_INBOUND_PROPERTY);

           if (inbound){
             SOAPMessage msg = msgCtxt.getMessage();
             msg.setProperty(javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING,"UTF-8");

             msgCtxt.Message(msg); //always put the message back where you found it.
           } 
       }      
     return true;
   }
```